# I think "git cherry-pick" just broke something

Tags: git

Our repo used to look like this:

```
* xxxxxxx (master, tag: v2.0.6c) Release v2.0.6c
|\
| * xxxxxxx (develop) Fixes and stuff
| * xxxxxxx Comment here
* | mmmmmmm (tag: v2.0.6b) Release v2.0.6b
|\|
| * xxxxxxx development branches!
. .
```

But now our repo looks like this:

```
* f8cb1b7 (origin/master, master) Do something on develop
*   86848aa Merge branch 'master' of ssh://...
|\  
| *   f6f8733 (HEAD, tag: v2.0.6c) Release v2.0.6c
| |\  
| * \   30bd2f2 (tag: v2.0.6b) Release v2.0.6b
| |\ \  
| * \ \   68bbe5b (tag: v2.0.6a) Release v2.0.6a
| |\ \ \  
| * \ \ \   35ceefe (tag: v2.0.6) Release v2.0.6
| |\ \ \ \  
* | \ \ \ \   15decce Merge branch 'develop' of ssh://...
|\ \ \ \ \ \  
| |/ / / / /  
|/| | | | |   
* | | | | |   806eebe (tag: v2.0.5a) Release v2.0.5a
|\ \ \ \ \ \  
.... etc. Branches keep expanding outwards for each tag/commit
```

All I know is that someone tried to cherry-pick a specific commit from develop onto master, committed it, and pushed it. Trying `git reset --hard HEAD^` didn't seem to do anything and I'm at a loss on how to fix it.

Comment: If you have the previous state of the git repository somewhere, you can add that as another remote and try to run `git diff old-origin/master..origin/master` to at least figure out the common parent before the new commits came in. This should help you narrow down which commits are the culprit.

Comment: Sorry if this is too blunt, but I really don't see how it's possible to more effectively obfuscate your question without a disciplined attempt.  Why did you strip half the sha's? If it's your master branch that's messed up, say `git reflog master` and then `git checkout -B master whereverlooksrighttoyou`.

Comment: @jthill The first part is a mockup. I can't copypaste a git log because, you know, the repo is kind of in the latter state.

Comment: @tuxdude I have a copy of a working state I can get to tomorrow. It doesn't seem to be a huge deal since it "works" now, but it makes the history almost unreadable...